# Expo ReactNative app Crah on Production but no errors on Development

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-dev-client

I was developing an app with `expo-cli`. When I try the app with the `developmentclient` there are no errors in the app, but when y run `eas build android` , I upload the .aab to google play and download to the mobile the app instantly crashes. I tried to install Sentry to debug the production app but the app crashes and there are no errors in Sentry dashboard. I don't know what more to do. The app goes right since I tried to install `react-native-iap` but it never worked, I removed but never again works
There are the packages I have:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@sentry/react-native": "5.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "^49.0.19",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "i18next": "^23.7.6",
    "ocr-space-api-wrapper": "^2.1.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "sentry-expo": "~7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "quip_quick"
}
```

Finaly, when I run npx expo-doctor sais there are no errors on the app.

I tried uninstalling lots of packages, debugging, etc. But yesterday it works fine 
Also with `npx expo start --no-dev` all works right.

Comment: What happens if you execute the following command `eas build --profile preview --platform android` without the development client in your `eas.json preview` object and run the application on an emulator or physical device?

Comment: It still crashes with preview.

Comment: Connect your terminal with the emulator or your physical device through `adb`, if you are connected, try running the following command `adb logcat "*:E"`, it should log all errors from your device & re open your application. Normally your error should be there!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it using `adb logcat "*:E" | findstr /C:"com.company.appName"`; I noticed that the error was with 'libreanimated.so.' Simply by uninstalling 'react-native-reanimated,' it's working now.